# directory index of "/var/www/app/" is forbidden

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

When I run nginx I get the following error: directory index of "/var/www/app/" is forbidden.
Here is the nginx configurations file that I have, here nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

And the following *.conf at conf.d directory

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    root /var/www/app;

    add_header  X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;

    location ~ /api/ {
         proxy_pass http://st-descriptors-back.envs.idevs.co;
         proxy_cache off;
    }

    location ~ /images/ {
         try_files $uri =404;
         expires 1y;
         add_header Cache-Control "private";
     }

    location ~ .(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|svgz|cur|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|heic|mp4)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        expires 1y;
        add_header Cache-Control "private";
    }

    location ~ ^.+\..+$ {
        try_files $uri /404.html =404;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        expires 1y;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
}
```

I have checked permissions for all the files at /var/www/app and all ownership and groups for that files, ownership and groups - nginx:nginx and permissions are drwxr-xr-x

Comment: Nginx is basically saying that `/var/www/app/index.html` does not exist.